# This static class field is being used before it's been created?

Tags: c++, static-variables, class-constants

So, I've been experimenting with static class fields (especially the constant ones), and got myself into.... this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class Test {
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Constructing (Default CTOR)\n"; }
    Test(int f) { std::cout << "Constructing (Int arg CTOR)\n"; }

    void method() const { std::cout << "Already constructed and being used\n"; }
};

class Stack {
public:
    // static const Test what{ 5 }; // - "element of type "const Test" can not have an initializer inside of a class"
    // const Test ok{ 5 }; // now it can (?)

    static const Test what;

    Stack() {
        what.method();
    }

    // Stack() : what{5} {} // can't do that because "what" will be dependent on object creation (which is not how static class fields roll)
};

Stack obj;

const Test Stack::what{};

int main()
{
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Apparently, `static const Test what` in `Stack` is being used before is has actually been created(?).

After that I ran another test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class Test {
public:
    int data;

    Test() { std::cout << "CONSTRUCTING (Default CTOR)\n"; } // notice, value-initialization of 'data' has been removed
    Test(int f) : data{ f } { std::cout << "CONSTRUCTING (Int arg CTOR)\n"; }

    void method() const { std::cout << "ALREADY CONSTRUCTED AND BEING USED :)\n" << data << std::endl; }
};

class Stack {
public:
    static const Test what;

    Stack() {
        what.method();
    }
};

Stack obj;

const Test Stack::what{ 5 };

int main()
{
    obj.what.method();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I was hoping to see some sort of error, but the output ended up looking like this:

[image: Output 2]

I have some assumptions on what is happening here, but I'm not sure if they're correct. So, if they are, please correct me.

Here are my assumptions:

Basically, static variables are created at the very start of the program (and are value-initialized) and destoyed at the very end of the program (when you actually close your .exe).
In my examples I have a static constant variable `what` in the class `Stack` and I think it is being created at the beginning of my program value-initialized. That's why its `data` field is set 0 and we can use its methods. But I don't think that's correct because it would've output `Constructing (Default CTOR)` into the console. So I'm kinda stuck there...

I also can not understand why the commented lines in my first example are illegal. What rules of static/constant class fields do they break exactly?

If you have any idea to what is happening in my examples please explain it.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I suspect it's related to the fact that the default constructor doesn't actually modify anything in the object. What happens if you change the second default constructor to have `: data {1}` ?

Comment: @Barmar, nothing. The output is still the same and there are no errors.

Comment: Because you `#include <conio.h>` I cannot compile your code. If you had stuck to standard C++ I might have been able to help you out.

Comment: @nwp There's only one line that depends on conio.h, `_getch(();`. Surely you can figure out how to replace that with standard C++.

Comment: @nwp Oh, that's just for me. To keep the console from closing. The code doesn't really depend on it, you can remove it or change it to `std::cin.get();`

Comment: I believe this is expected behavior.  Constructors for static objects are called in the order they appear in the compilation unit; the order of construction for static objects in different compilation units is undefined.  You are able to reference an unconstructed static object from code called from a static constructor.  Unlike some languages, there is no "class constructor" that is called before static objects in the class are referenced.  Now I invite people who actually read the spec to point out where I am wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables at namespace scope (i.e. not inside a function) are constructed in the order of their definitions in the source file.  This ordering only applies between variables in the same source file, not between different source files.

So `obj` is always constructed before `what`. There are limited things that can be done with objects that have a constructor but before the constructor has been called;  and invoking a member function is not one of them (C++14 [basic.life]/5.2).  So the call `what.method()` in `Stack`'s constructor causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the informative answer! So the zero in my second exmaple's output should've been an error after all :)